# default content for extends tag - django

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there any way of having default content for a block?

Something that would work like this:

```
if extended:
   show content from template extending it
else:
   show this default content
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ordinary [`Template Inheritance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Define a block in your parent (base) template as a container for your default data.

Now, when you extend this template you can decide what to to with this block.
If you don't override the block the default data is shown. Otherwise the data from the block in you inherited template gets displayed.

Finally `{{ block.super }}` gives you the option to mix the contents from the base and the inherited template:

> This is useful if
>   you want to add to the contents of a parent block instead of
>   completely overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the implementations of builtins tags inside django/template/defaulttags.py, for example `autoescape`

```
# in autoescape()
# get content from current autoecape to pairing endautoescape
nodelist = parser.parse(('endautoescape',))

# in AutoEsacpeControlNode.render()
# render inner content
output = self.nodelist.render(context)
```

Thus you write something like following in your customized tag

```
def render(self, context):
    ...
    if extend:
        return default_content
    else:
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

Normally `if... else` will do the trick also...:

```
{% if extended %}
...
{% else %}
{{ default }}
{% endif %}
```